# Internet Explorer 9 beta installation problem

Tags: windows-vista, internet-explorer

I'm running Vista SP2, x64. Because I wanted to test out the IE9 beta, I downloaded the English-language installer for 64-bit Vista systems. Running the installer is fine until it starts downloading required updates. The progress bar doesn't get far before it completely stops moving. Then after 20 minutes to an hour, it will tell me that there's an update I have to install, but as soon as I click OK it sends me an error message, telling me that it can't go to the url of the update [which is here](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=184111). So I manually enter it into my browser, which prompts me to download a standalone update. After that's been downloaded and I run it, it tells me that the update does not apply to my system.

I'd appreciate any help to solving my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, Reboot the system, then go to Windows Update and make sure you have all critical and IE related updates installed. I would recommend loading *ALL* updates.

The try downloading the full install package locally from this link --

http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=5043cbb0-857c-4708-b819-cc52234f8714

The typically links have you install a small downloader whereas the above link has you download the entire IE9 Beta Package. Once the download finishes, execute the installer. If it tells you that you need additional updates, let it try to get them. If not, they try to download the updates as full packages, install them, and try the IE9 install again.

Comment: Chris, much thanks for your help. But, the link you gave leads to the same file as the official test drive page, and running it gives me the same problem, even after updates (which was just Windows Live) and a reboot. I'm not sure how to download the updates as fully packages, however the url the setup fails to visit now redirects to a requirements page with some links to some updates, so I'm going to install those even though Windows Update says my computer is updated.

Comment: Installed one of the updates, the other didn't apply to my system, and the installation worked. When I launch it, it tries to go directly to google.com but then I get a popup saying that Internet Explorer has stopped working and the notification thing slides out from the bottom of the screen, and it tries to reload the tab and it happens again, so it is unable to load any websites at all.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to re-install while booted up in Safe Mode. This requires that you have the installer files local -or- Boot to Safe Mode w/Networking Support if you do not have all the installer files local.

This can help reduce locked files/registry during install and possibly correct the issue.

Chris

Answer (score 0):

for installing IE9 there are two solutions for you.

1. Reset the windows update and then download & install are mandatory updates.
2. This solution is easy:

Install the Win 7 Sp1 pack . You can download this from 
https://www.microsoft.com/betaexperience/pd/W7SP1/enus/

Restart your machine and try installing IE9 build . If it ask to Close Windows Explorer (explorer.exe) or Ignore it. Select the option of Ignore as it will give you fast installation. after completion , Restart your machine and enjoy.